# How to rotate uwp usercontrol smoothly?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created a user control having some textboxes, images, etc. Now I want to rotate that usercontrol with mouse. I have managed to rotate successfully, but it inverts during rotation, where am I doing mistake? Below is my xaml & code behind:

```
<UserControl...
    <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid"
    Width="300" Height="400" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,Rotate"
    ManipulationStarted="Manipulator_OnManipulationStarted"
    ManipulationDelta="Manipulator_OnManipulationDelta">

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateGrid" Angle="0"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

    <!-- some elements -->
    <Rectangle x:Name="RotateRectangle"
    IsHitTestVisible="False"
    Width="16" Height="16"
    Fill="Red"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>


private void Manipulator_OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Position.X > ContainerGrid.Width - RotateRectangle.Width && 
    e.Position.Y < ContainerGrid.Height - RotateRectangle.Height)
    {
    _isRotating = true;
    lastPosition = e.Position;
    return;
    }

    _isRotating = false;
}


private void Manipulator_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (_isRotating)
    {
    Point currentLocation = e.Position;
    double radians = Math.Atan2((currentLocation.Y - lastPosition.Y),     (currentLocation.X - lastPosition.X));
    var angle = radians * 180 / Math.PI;
    RotateGrid.Angle = angle;
    lastPosition = currentLocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/cleaner/smoother to do this in Blend?

Comment: I am not rotating this element using storyboards, that is easier as you said. But, I want the rotating functionality given to user, using mouse, so implemented in this way. User has to rotate the element using mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing... you want to rotate the 2D object in the plane of the screen, right?  (That's what I assumed from your transformation.)  So why are you using both x and y mouse positions?  Your rotation is a scalar value, so you should just be using 1-axis of your mouse movement.

If you instead want to rotate your object by having your mouse grab an imaginary ring around the object and rotate that... then you should instead be keeping a reference to your start position relative to the object's center or the starting angle of the mouse relative to the object's center.  Something like this maybe:

```
private void Manipulator_OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Position.X > ContainerGrid.Width - RotateRectangle.Width && 
    e.Position.Y < ContainerGrid.Height - RotateRectangle.Height)
    {
    _isRotating = true;
    var startingRadians = Math.Atan2((currentLocation.Y - objectCenter.Y),     (currentLocation.X - objectCenter.X));
    startingAngle = startingRadians * 180 / Math.PI;
    return;
    }

    _isRotating = false;
}

private void Manipulator_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (_isRotating)
    {
    Point currentLocation = e.Position;
    double radians = Math.Atan2((currentLocation.Y - objectCenter.Y),     (currentLocation.X - objectCenter.X));
    var angle = radians * 180 / Math.PI;
    RotateGrid.Angle = angle-startingAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to rotate my 2D object about it's center, in the plane of the screen. Not on the path of imaginary ring. my code rotates but inverts to 360 degrees unexpectedly, not able to solve that! How can I do that without both x & y positions? If I use only the X position, how do I know whether it is rotating clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen please check if you has use `RotateInertia` model. for more you could refer uwp basic input code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput).